How delete a substring part within filename of several files (matching a certain filename pattern) in Python?
I am trying to eliminate some part of file names so I could use for pattern to ingest data daily.
I have following files inside this folder (F:\Source).
WH_BEE_FULL_20241017_170853_1.bak
WH_BEE_FULL_20241017_170853_2.bak
WH_BEE_FULL_20241017_170853_3.bak
WH_BEE_FULL_20241017_170853_4.bak
WH_BEE_FULL_20241017_170853_5.bak
WH_BEE_FULL_20241017_170853_6.bak

I need to delete "170853" part of file name, so that end result would be:
WH_BEE_FULL_20241017_1.bak
WH_BEE_FULL_20241017_2.bak
WH_BEE_FULL_20241017_3.bak
WH_BEE_FULL_20241017_4.bak
WH_BEE_FULL_20241017_5.bak
WH_BEE_FULL_20241017_6.bak

So, "20241017" is changeable daily as it is "YYYYMMDD" format, but other fields (like "WH", "BEE", "FULL" & "_1 ~ _6") would be static.
After renaming, those files would be relocated to (F:\Destination) folder.
How do I go about doing it in Python?

@JonSG Thank you for your feedback. I think the difference is that it is not renaming it, but I am trying to eliminate. Let me change the title of the post.

@Java, your old title was clearer by the way.
